# VueJS: Why this data property doesn't updated on click event in Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-devtools

In the code below, the `getWidth` event handler (defined in the `methods` object) updates the `data.width` property. As it updates, the variable `width` should be shown live in VueJS's Chrome addon.

However, that live update doesn't show up in the Vue DevTools. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the code or what am I doing wrong. The add-on isn't a problem since I've tested in Firefox too.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <p :style="{width: 200 + 'px'}" class="box">{{msg}}</p>
  <button v-on:click="getWidth">New Width</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'Test Message',
    mywidth: ''
  },
  methods: { 
    getWidth: function(){
      this.mywidth = 20 * 2;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Most JS Function calls need () to execute the function.  I'm new to Vue as well so not sure if it's needed.  But where you have v-on:click="getWidth", what happens if you add the () at the end of getWidth.  So v-on:click="getWidth()"

Comment: @DylanWright `()` isn't required to execute the method. However if you there's a variable you'd want to pass to the method then you'd pass that using `()` something as `(width)`.

Comment: how `mywidth` is related with `width` ?

Comment: @user2486 they aren't related.

Comment: Well, you are using **width** in <p> and it appears nowhere else in the supplied code.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you aren't actually using your `mywidth` data property anywhere.

The [Vue DevTools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) only updates its references to the Vue component's data properties when they are accessed in code, not when they are set.

Simply use that data property somewhere (like putting `{{ mywidth }}` in the template) and it'll be updated in the Vue DevTools extension.

Comment: @appu This is assuming you mistyped when you say "the variable `width` should be shown live in VueJS's Chrome addon" and that you meant `mywidth`. Your component doesn't have a `width` property defined.